# How to write and read data in a file using IO and different streams in java?

Tags: java

How to write and read data in a file using IO and different streams in java ?

I am  trying to write data in the ABC.txt file whic is inside a file (say XYZ) and by using Input/ Output stream of byte and char stream ??

Give broad explanation please ?

This is what I have so far:

```
import java.io.*; 
class WriteData1 { 
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException { 
        System.out.println("TRyimg to write in the text"); 
        PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(System.out); 
        ps.println("Hi"); 
        ps.println("Its show time"); 
        ps.close(); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: What U tried So far..??

Comment: Till now  import java.io.*;
class WriteData1
{
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
 {
  System.out.println("TRyimg to write in the text");
  PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(System.out);
  ps.println("Hi");
  ps.println("Its show time");
  ps.close();
 }
}

Comment: And M trying to put the content in the .txt file

Comment: @HrishiDDeveloper I've edited your question to include the code you put in the comment, but you should get in the habit of [edit]ing your own question (or better yet, include all the relevant information in the first place!).

Comment: As for your problem... you never actually do anything with any files of any kind in the code you've provided. What are you expecting? What *exactly* isn't working?

Comment: Look whatever am writing in the ps.println. I want to write the same in my a file ? Now I don't know how to do so ??

Comment: Take a look at a File, pass that into the PrintStream http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using PrintStream you should pass a File as an argument.

```
   PrintStream ps = new PrintStream( new File("ABC.txt"));
```